# PHP create row for every three sets of data

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am working on this project where i need to load the different items in the menu. My idea was to use a foreach loop to go through it, which works i get the items, but i can not figure out how to create the row for every 3 items.

**HTML**

```
     <div class="row box-2">
                <div class="grid_4">
                    <div class="img"><div class="lazy-img" style="padding-bottom: 76.21621621621622%;"><img data-src="images/page-4_img07.jpg" alt=""></div></div>
                    <h3>Anteger convallis orci vel mi nelaoreet, at ornare lorem consequat. </h3>
                    <p>Vestibulum volutpatturpis ut massa commodo, quis aliquam massa facilisis.Integer convavel miberto merlonelaoreet, at ornare lorem consequat.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_4">
                    <div class="img"><div class="lazy-img" style="padding-bottom: 76.21621621621622%;"><img data-src="images/page-4_img08.jpg" alt=""></div></div>
                    <h3>Genteger convallis orci vel mi nelaoreet, at ornare lorem consequat.</h3>
                    <p>Meestibulum volutpatturpis ut massa commodo, quis aliquam massa facilisis.Integer convavel miberto merlonelaoreet, at ornare lorem consequatre. </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_4">
                    <div class="img"><div class="lazy-img" style="padding-bottom: 76.21621621621622%;"><img data-src="images/page-4_img09.jpg" alt=""></div></div>
                    <h3>Ternteger convallis orci vel mi nelaoreet, at ornare lorem consequat. </h3>
                    <p>Testibulum volutpatturpis ut massa commodo, quis aliquam massa facilisis.Integer convavel miberto merlonelaoreet, at ornare lorem consequ.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
            foreach ($menuItems as $dish => $item) { 
            ?>

        <div class="grid_4">
            <div class="img"><div class="lazy-img" style="padding-bottom: 76.21621621621622%;"><img data-src="images/<?php echo $item[img];?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $item[name]; ?>"></div></div>
            <h3><?php echo $item[title]; ?></h3>
            <a href="dish.php?item=<?php echo $dish; ?>" class="btn">Read more about <?php echo $item[title]; ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php 
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php $i = 1; ?>
   <?php 
        foreach ($menuItems as $dish => $item) { 
        ?>
    <?php if($i % 3 == 0 || $i == 1) { ?>
         <div class="row box">
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="img"><div class="lazy-img" style="padding-bottom: 76.21621621621622%;"><img data-src="images/<?php echo $item[img];?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $item[name]; ?>"></div></div>
        <h3><?php echo $item[title]; ?></h3>
        <a href="dish.php?item=<?php echo $dish; ?>" class="btn">Read more about <?php echo $item[title]; ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php if($i % 3 == 0 || $i == 1) { ?>
         </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php 
    } ?>
```

Comment: This code makes it create a row for each item i need it to create a row every 3 item

Answer (score 0):

So if I am not mistaken, for example if you have 7 items you get 3 rows. 2 rows with 3 items and 1 row with 1 item?

Perhaps this setup can help you with your menu:

```
<?php
$itemsForRow = 3;
$itemTemplate = <<<'TEMPLATE'
    <div class="img"><div class="lazy-img" style="padding-bottom: 76.21621621621622%;"><img data-src="images/%2$s.jpg" alt="%1$s"></div></div>
    <h3>%1$s</h3>
    <a href="dish.php?item=%3$s" class="btn">Read more about %1$s</a>
TEMPLATE;

if (count($menuItems) > 0) {
    $itemCounter = 0;
    foreach ($menuItems as $dish => $item) {
        if ($itemsForRow > 0 && $itemCounter % $itemsForRow === 0) {
            echo '<div class="grid_4">';
        }
        echo sprintf(
            $itemTemplate,
            $item["name"],
            $item["title"],
            $item["img"],
            $dish
        );
        if ($itemsForRow > 0 && ($itemCounter % $itemsForRow === ($itemsForRow - 1) || $itemCounter == count($menuItems) - 1)) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        $itemCounter++;
    }
}
?>
```